# Javascript not working in Grails

Tags: javascript, grails, gsp

I have a simple script works fine in html. Yet in a gsp, it doesn't work anymore.

My script is very simple, as below:

```
// program variables
var displayElement;

// constants
var maxLength = 300;

// calculator variables
var text;
var currentLength;
var dotPosition;

var lastNumber;
var currentNumber;
var rememberedNumber;
var operator;

alert('hello22');

function parseNumber(number) {
        if ((number == -1) && (dotPosition > 0) || (maxLength == currentLength)) return;
        if (currentLength == 0) text = '';
        currentLength++;
        if (number == -1) {
                text += '.';
                dotPosition = currentLength;
        } else text += number;

        displayElement.value = text;
}

function parseBackspace() {
        if (currentLength == 0) return;
        if ('.' == text[currentLength-1]) dotPosition = 0;
        text = text.slice(0, currentLength-1);
        if(--currentLength == 0) text = '';
        displayElement.value = text;
}

function parseClearEntry() {
        currentLength = 0;
        text = '0';
        dotPosition = 0;
        displayElement.value = text;
}

function parseClear() {
        parseClearEntry();
        lastNumber = 0;
        operator = '';
        //added by Kevin
        displayElement.value = '';
}

function initAll() {
        alert('hello1113333333');
        text = '0';
        currentNumber = 0;
        currentLength = 0;
        displayElement = document.getElementById('TextBox');
        rememberedNumber = 0;
        lastNumber = 0;
        dotPosition = 0;
        alert('hello1111111111');
}
```

When I included into the gsp view page, I put `<g:javascript src="getKey.js" />` between the `<head></head>`.

Then I call the function initAll() like `<body onload="initAll()">`, and others like `<div class="holder"><input type="button" class="buttonstyle" value="7" name="Seven" onclick="parseNumber(7)" /></div>`

Can anyone tell me what's wrong? I am sure the script has been included correctly because the alert "hello22" was threw.

Comment: You should probably do a "view source" to see what things look like when the page makes it to the browser.  Also, you might want to explain exactly what you mean by this "not working" - are there errors? weird effects? wrong effects? erratic behavior? etc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put somewhere following code at the footer:

```
<g:script>
(function() { initAll(); })();
</g:script>
```

or

```
<g:script>
window.onload = initAll; //note that is's without braces
</g:script>
```

instead of `<body onload="initAll"`

Comment: I know what's wrong... the layout replace everything... so... it works after i put it into the layout. Thanks!!